# Outlook Add in: messageCompose vs message

Tags: angular, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to find out whether the currently open email in outlook is of type messageCompose or message (I.e, my add in is trying to figure out if the user is writing an email, or reading an email).

In both cases
Office.context.mailbox.item.itemType
is "message"

However, when I 
console.log(Office.context.mailbox.item)
I see the following in chrome inspect[image] (r.message) if I am reading an email and [image] (r.messageCompose) if I am composing an email.

Basically what I want is

```
if(I am writing an email) {
 // do stuff
}
if(I am reading an email) {
 // do other stuff
}
```

Also, is there a way to distinguish between composing a new message, and replying to a message?

I'm using Angular 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In an Outlook addin, how to check whether we are in compose mode or read mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293787/in-an-outlook-addin-how-to-check-whether-we-are-in-compose-mode-or-read-mode)

Comment: @SlavaIvanov i took a look, I don't think so. Also i do have        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface"> in my manifest

Comment: I don't understand your comment ... You "don't think so" what? The answer exactly talks about  "MessageComposeCommandSurface" and "MessageReadCommandSurface" extension points.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293787/in-an-outlook-addin-how-to-check-whether-we-are-in-compose-mode-or-read-mode .