# Is there way to determine form type of appointment when using outlook add-in/office.js

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

Form type of appointment cab be defined in add-in manifest  as folowing

```
 <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read"/>
```

if an appointment already created, is there way to know current outlook add-in is running outlook edit mode or read mode using office js which looks like as following ?

```
if(Office.context.mailbox.item.FormType =="Read"){
  //
}
```

[image]

Comment: Another SO user had a similar query here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293787/in-an-outlook-addin-how-to-check-whether-we-are-in-compose-mode-or-read-mode". Let us know if this helped

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define separate landing pages with actions to run in the manifest:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>FunctionSpecificToReadView</FunctionName>
</Action>
</ExtensionPoint>
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>FunctionSpecificToComposeView</FunctionName>
</Action>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

If you don't want to create two separate landing pages for read and compose modes you may check for the `displayReplyForm` API, this is available in the read mode. If this is not defined then you are in compose mode:

```
if (Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm != undefined) {
  // read mode
} else {
  // compose mode
}
```